# PyInstaller WARNING: lib not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I know this type of question has been asked here before, but I did not find a working solution to it. I have a python file which I want to convert to an exe on Windows 10. I ran `pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole myfile.py`, and it outputted *a lot* of warnings:

```
C:\Users\conne\Desktop\Python >pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole normal.py
277 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
277 INFO: Python: 3.6.2
278 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0
279 INFO: wrote C:\Users\conne\Desktop\Python\normal.spec
280 INFO: UPX is not available.
283 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\conne\\Desktop\\python',
 'C:\\Users\\conne\\Desktop\\python']
283 INFO: checking Analysis
284 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
284 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
286 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
289 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5055 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
5058 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
5145 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
5225 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
5298 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
5371 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
5442 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
5526 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
5598 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
5669 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
5753 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
5840 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
6061 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6134 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6208 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6282 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6354 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6430 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6503 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6576 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6651 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6725 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6798 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6879 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
6882 INFO: Caching module hooks...
6892 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\conne\Desktop\python meterpreter\normal.py
6898 INFO: Loading module hooks...
6899 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
7055 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
7057 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
7351 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
7351 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
7360 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
7439 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
7515 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
7589 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
7660 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
7731 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
7813 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
7895 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
7968 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
8051 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
8133 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
8213 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
8286 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
8361 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
8440 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
8512 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
8585 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
8658 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
8741 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
8815 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
8887 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
8958 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
9032 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
9116 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
9194 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
9271 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
9344 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
9428 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
9501 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
9580 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
9651 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
9723 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
9801 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
9874 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
9959 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_socket.pyd
10030 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_socket.pyd
10115 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\select.pyd
10123 INFO: Looking for eggs
10123 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
10124 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
10128 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\conne\Desktop\python\build\normal\warnnormal.txt
10196 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\conne\Desktop\python\build\normal\xref-normal.html
10212 INFO: checking PYZ
10212 INFO: Building PYZ because out00-PYZ.toc is non existent
10213 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\conne\Desktop\python\build\normal\out00-PYZ.pyz
10948 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\conne\Desktop\python\build\normal\out00-PYZ.pyz completed successfully.
10958 INFO: checking PKG
10958 INFO: Building PKG because out00-PKG.toc is non existent
10959 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
12884 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg completed successfully.
12887 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\conne\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
12887 INFO: checking EXE
12888 INFO: Building EXE because out00-EXE.toc is non existent
12888 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
12916 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\conne\Desktop\python meterpreter\dist\normal.exe
13011 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc completed successfully.
```

As you can see the exe is created successfully, but it doesn't work as it should when running it.

EDIT:
I ran it with debug enabled and apparently it can't import ctypes, it throws a name error. It only does this when running with pyinstaller, when running as a .py file it works fine.

Comment: Can you please post the error messages associated with the failure to run the program? These will be more helpful in determining why the application does not work. To see these error messages, run the program from a console: `/path/to/app/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` for Mac (in Terminal), `/path/to/app/dist/MyApp.exe` for Windows (in Command Prompt)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [516808 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685364/516808-warning-lib-not-found-api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0-dll-dependency-of-c)

Comment: I find it unlikely that those errors cause it to not run. I get them and my exe's run perfectly fine.  They are related to python 32 bit. I answered a very similar question yesterday.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685364/516808-warning-lib-not-found-api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0-dll-dependency-of-c .  The reason you are likely getting not running exe is because of  windowed mode.  More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685217/windowed-mode-cannot-run/48685637#48685637 .  Note I never use windowed mode myself on windows.

Comment: @Dragomeow It's not in windowed mode, it's supposed to run in the background. Check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it threw a `NameError` when importing ctypes, adding this line to the pyinstaller command solved the issue: `--hidden-import ctypes`

Comment: It's supposed to be --hidden-import ctypes

Comment: doens't work for me. Addind the path to the missing dll worked instead

Answer (score 12):

I found the DLL's in system32/downlevel and syswow64/downlevel and copied all of them to the respective parent folders (system32 and syswow64). Something that Ritesh Singh's command will do. Try a restart after copying if it still does not work.

EDIT: As mentioned in comments, using `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\System32\downlevel;` before using pyinstaller or adding the downlevel folders to path in env variables might be a better idea.(not tested)

Comment: You can also run this before PyInstaller `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\System32\downlevel;`

Comment: @raffamaiden: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

> 26095 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\DLLs\select.pyd

Search in C: drive for dll and set the path in pyinstaller command. The below command fixed the above pyinstaller error in windows 10:

```
pyinstaller --paths C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft-windows-m..namespace-downlevel_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_50c6cb8431e7428f hello.py
```

Answer (score 5):

I just added the path in the environmental variable, it worked for me.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x64

(or)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Redist\ucrt\DLLs\x86

Comment: Adding C:\Windows\System32\downlevel worked for me as well. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 4):

When there is a whole slew of WARNINGS coming from pyinstaller about not being able to locate Windows DLLs, you might check to see if they're in one of the two following locations:

```
C:\Windows\System32\downlevel
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\downlevel
```

You can add one or both to the PATH variable, like so and those warnings should disappear:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Windows\System32\downlevel
```

I mention this because it's easier than finding and copying the DLLs to a folder on the path like Alex F mentioned.  I also noticed some of the DLLs you're unable to locate are in the folders I called out above.

Answer (score 3):

Note that as of 4/3/2019 the current dev version of pyinstaller 3.5 does not show these warnings.  (3.5.dev0+g8c27d266)

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git
```

Comment: Good find dude!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to install one of the Visual C++ packages bellow according to your system architecture.

---

## The latest supported Visual C++ downloads

### Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019

---

Download the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/). The following updates are the latest supported Visual C++ redistributable packages for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019. Included is a baseline version of the Universal C Runtime see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/universal-crt-deployment?view=vs-2019) for details.

- x86: [vc_redist.x86.exe](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x86.exe)
- x64: [vc_redist.x64.exe](https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)

**Note** Visual C++ 2015, 2017 and 2019 all share the same redistributable files.

For example, installing the Visual C++ 2019 redistributable will affect programs built with Visual C++ 2015 and 2017 also. However, installing the Visual C++ 2015 redistributable will not replace the newer versions of the files installed by the Visual C++ 2017 and 2019 redistributables.

This is different from all previous Visual C++ versions, as they each had their own distinct runtime files, not shared with other versions.

### Visual Studio 2013 (VC++ 12.0)

---

- Download the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3179560). This is the latest supported Visual C++ redistributable package for Visual Studio 2013.
- Download [Multibyte MFC Library for Visual Studio 2013](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=1430). This add-on for Visual Studio 2013 contains the multibyte character set (MBCS) version of the Microsoft Foundation Class (MFC) Library.
- Download [Visual C++ 2013 Runtime for Sideloaded Windows 8.1 apps](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/0/5f0f8404-9329-44a9-8176-ed6f7f746f25/vclibs_redist_packages.zip).

For more information, see [C++ Runtime for Sideloaded Windows 8.1 apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/08/01/c-runtime-for-sideloaded-windows-8-1-apps.aspx) on [the VC++ Team Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/).

### Visual Studio 2012 (VC++ 11.0)

---

Download the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=1452). This is the latest supported Visual C++ redistributable package for Visual Studio 2012.

### Visual Studio 2010 (VC++ 10.0) SP1

---

- Download the [Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 (Installer)](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=963). This is the latest supported Visual C++ service pack for Visual Studio 2010.

  Note

  This web installer requires an internet connection. This installer downloads and installs Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1. It works for all editions of Visual Studio 2010 (Express, Professional, Premium, Ultimate, and Test Professional).
- Download the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=26999). This is the latest supported Visual C++ redistributable package update for Visual Studio 2010.

### Visual Studio 2008 (VC++ 9.0) SP1

---

- Visual Studio 2008 reached [end of support on April 10, 2018](https://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search?alpha=Visual%20Studio%202008). To aid the discovery of the latest downloads, the links are retained currently, but may be removed in the future.
- Download the [Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (Installer)](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?pid=620). This is the latest Visual C++ service pack for Visual Studio 2008. This service pack improved responsiveness, stability, and performance.
  **Note** This download installs Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 and Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.
- Download the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Security Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=26368). This is the latest Visual C++ redistributable package update for Visual Studio 2008.

---

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and none of the documented pyinstaller fix actions worked. I was able to resolve this by downloading the DLLs (I got them from the SDK package) and copying them into system32 and sysWOW64. All programs are now backwards compatible!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the next steps to solve the ***"PyInstaller WARNING:lib not found:api-ms-win-crt SOLUTION"*** problem:

1. run the following command line in command prompt or windows power-shell
2. pyinstaller --windowed --paths C:\Windows\System32\downlevel application_name.py

Additional information can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/27709d78-dfe1-4766-b5e3-99db198f3807/missing-apimswincoreheapl210dll-windows-10-64-bit?forum=visualstudiogeneral) at the MS website.