# Pyinstaller EXE file crashes upon start

Tags: python, crash, pyinstaller

I'm not sure if I am doing this right, this is my first time asking questions and it is about packing my little python program into EXE file that could run on any laptop. So I tried both cx_freeze and pyisntaller, it turns out that cx_freeze could not even install successfully and pyinstaller works, however the EXE file it generated automatically crashed without doing anything. My python program does not have any GUI and it is supposed to generate something upon start and then ask you to input data. Is it something wrong with my python code or the pyinstaller? 
Because I tried both on my personal laptop and the desktop in the lab, different environment, same result.

The code is attached below is from pyinstaller, it seems that there are a lot of warnings.

Looking forward to your help guys, I need this running tomorrow....

```
2324 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
2340 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
2359 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
2375 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
2393 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
2479 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
2495 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
2511 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
2528 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
2546 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
2564 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
2581 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
2599 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
2615 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
2631 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
2647 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
2666 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
2686 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
2703 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
2719 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
2737 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
2753 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\VCRUNTIME140.dll
2756 INFO: Caching module hooks...
2760 INFO: Analyzing D:\Test\DBS_real.py
2820 INFO: Loading module hooks...
2820 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
2882 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
2883 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
3039 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
3039 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
3043 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
3063 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3079 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3096 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3112 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3128 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3144 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3160 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3178 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3194 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3212 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_ssl.pyd
3236 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3252 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3270 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3286 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3303 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\pyexpat.pyd
3323 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
3339 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
3355 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
3371 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
3389 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
3407 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
3424 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
3441 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
3457 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
3478 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
3495 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_lzma.pyd
3514 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_socket.pyd
3532 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_socket.pyd
3554 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
3570 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
3586 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\unicodedata.pyd
3612 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
3628 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
3644 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
3660 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
3678 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\_bz2.pyd
3697 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\DLLs\select.pyd
3700 INFO: Looking for eggs
3700 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python36.dll
3700 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
3707 INFO: Warnings written to D:\Test\build\DBS_real\warn-DBS_real.txt
3735 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to D:\Test\build\DBS_real\xref-DBS_real.html
3768 INFO: checking PYZ
3768 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
3769 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\Test\build\DBS_real\PYZ-00.pyz
4045 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\Test\build\DBS_real\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
4054 INFO: checking PKG
4054 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
4055 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
5163 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
5168 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\jinze\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
5168 INFO: checking EXE
5168 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
5169 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
5169 INFO: Appending archive to EXE D:\Test\dist\DBS_real.exe
5358 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Comment: Did [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712154/pyinstaller-warning-lib-not-found) not help? They mentioned the need to add certain things to your path, did you try that with no luck?

Comment: I tired but it didn't work, I finally did it running in anaconda environment. Though a lot of people said you need to uninstall anaconda before doing this....Thanks for your hint bro!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyInstaller WARNING: lib not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712154/pyinstaller-warning-lib-not-found)

Comment: You need to post the error on the console while running the exe file. In all probability, your code might be referring to an input file, which is not taken care by the Pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

There is a conversation here about the warning you are getting. https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1566

Unfortunately from what I am reading there it seems pyinstaller does not work on windows 10 without some very big extra steps.