# Pyinstaller "Failed to execute script pyiboot01_bootstrap"

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm using pyinstaller to produce an exectuable for a python program. But, whenever I try to use a generated executable, I get a message window that reads "Failed to execute script ...".

The command I'm running is `pyinstaller -w run.py`. But, when run with the `--debug` option a different error is made apparent. "Failed to execute script pyiboot-1_bootstrap". After this error it kills the program.

I tried with the `-F` option and that did not change the outcome. All the files I created for the project are in the same directory. I did get warnings that dll's weren't being included but I [resolved that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712154/pyinstaller-warning-lib-not-found).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pyinstaller doesn't like the built in `quit()` function I was using.

Instead use `sys.exit()` to close the program.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747371/python-exit-commands-why-so-many-and-when-should-each-be-used) to see why `sys.exit()` is better practice for production code.

Comment: What was the "quit()" function? Did you make it yourself or was it imported from somewhere?

Comment: I believe it was a python method

Comment: Usually gives error when you quit the program

Answer (score 5):

What I found useful was to make an exe of my .py script in console mode and then run it. For a very short period of time, I saw an error message in the console window. I had to screenshot it to read completely. So one of the imports was missing from the folder in which I had my script. I opened cmd from the location bar of that folder (by typing cmd there) and imported modules using **pip install <module_name>**.
Sorry for the long answer, I am a newbie.