# im getting `pyiboot01_bootstrap` pyinstaller error

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

When i tried to open my .exe file which is created using pyinstaller ,its showing `failed to execute pyiboot01_bootstrap`. I created a simple pygame, which contain audio, image and some code.

Command i used to create my .exe file was

`pyinstaller  main.py --noconsole --debug all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `--onefile` argument also. Since your game contains images and audio files the most probable problem is that you have not moved your `.exe` from dist folder to the folder where is your `main.py` so the paths to those images and audio files are incorrect. And if you have not already, update pygame to `2.0.0.dev6` or `dev8`, because from personal experience pygame `1.9.6` in certain cases cause error when audio files are present. These steps should solve the issue.

EDIT: Answer on comment

Oh, I did not know that you used font. 2 possible fixes, had the same issue. First use some "standard" fonts like "Arial".

```
font = pg.font.SysFont("Arial", FONT_SIZE, True)
```

or put the font you want to use (`freesansbold.ttf`) in the same folder as `.exe` First option will work for sure.

Comment: yah, i tried with `--onefile`, and i already have the latest version of pygame.But still the same

Comment: Ok, did you move the file so the paths stay correct? Also try removing audio file, only leave image, see if it is going to work. I searched about this error, maybe it has to do with "exiting". See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56957022/pyinstaller-failed-to-execute-script-pyiboot01-bootstrap)

Comment: Bro,  when i remove the font that i used in my code, it is working properly, `font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 32))`.How to fix this..?